# Load balancing in distributed system

Tags: soa, distributed, distributed-computing, microservices

Given:

- n producers and m consumers, n >> m
- consumers make requests to producers for data
- any producer can be used by only one consumer at a time i.e. consumer can work with multiple producers but producer must work with single consumer

Needed:

- Consumers need to coordinate so every consumer can own subset of producers.
- If consumer goes down, other consumers should take his producers.
- Consumers should exchange producers to ensure equal load on consumers.

Question:

Are there papers/algorithms/libraries for that case or should I invent another wheel?

Comment: did you try Apache Kafka an Zookeeper?

Comment: That is exactly the case. Kafka topic as producer can only be used by single consumer. If we have n Kafka topics, we should distribute them somehow between m consumers

Comment: As i know, Zookeeper will handles m consumers and load-balancing between them.

Comment: You can use a message queue system also it seem fit for your problems if you don't need synchronous communication of course.

Comment: @cool unfortunately that will not do - message streams from producers must be ordered, separated and processed on different nodes to ensure scalability

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a client side LB like SmartStack (http://nerds.airbnb.com/smartstack-service-discovery-cloud/), Baker Street (http://bakerstreet.io), or Consul HAProxy (https://hashicorp.com/blog/haproxy-with-consul.html), along with a custom load balancing / routing algorithm.

All of these systems us HAProxy to proxy your requests intelligently between producer/consumer. The proxy itself uses a service discovery mechanism to figure out what's available. You'd need to make some changes to the service discovery mechanism to return the right result based on your constraints noted above.